# Add class to data received from Mongo based on a field value in Mongo, on a Meteor app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, helper, spacebars

I got mongo collection documents which includes an array which includes bunch of other objects. This is for a simple chat app.

I access all the data within the document and display it. Nonetheless, I have difficulties to give `my-message` class to *my* messages. When I write this below code, it gives **all** messages `my-message` class. :/

So what am I doing wrong?

Object Structure:

```
{
  _id: "RCe9ZBS9PfkwrqKvg"
  borrowerId: "Rg33iLJyRYqHyMpk4"
  messages: Array[{text:messageBody, from:currentUserId, date:New Date()}]
  ownerId: "fPv5yWJiSqFX3bAhR"
  reqId: "KXErmpFJ7LiCbKsqc"
}
```

Template:

```
  {{#with getMessages}}
    {{#each messages}}
        <p class="{{#if myMessages}} my-message {{/if}}">{{text}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  {{/with}}
```

Helper:

```
Template.reqMessages.helpers({
  getMessages: function () {
    var theReqId = FlowRouter.getParam("reqId");
    return Messages.findOne({reqId: theReqId});
  },
  myMessages: function () {
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    var theReqId = FlowRouter.getParam("reqId");
    return Messages.find({reqId: theReqId, 
      messages: [{$elemMatch: {
        from: currentUserId
      }}]});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to do this:

```
{{#with getMessages}}
  {{#each messages}}
    <p class="{{#if isMine}}my-message{{/if}}">{{text}}</p>
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}

Template.reqMessages.helpers({
  getMessages: function () {
    var theReqId = FlowRouter.getParam("reqId");
    return Messages.findOne({reqId: theReqId});
  },
  isMine: function () {
    return this.from === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

Since you are already looping through the messages array in your template, the helper's context (this) is each object in the array. You can determine if it is from the user by simply comparing `this.from` and `Meteor.userId()`.

Comment: You're awesome! I just had to put 'return' in the beginning. Then it worked!

Comment: yep! sorry bout that, I've been writing a lot of Coffeescript lately :-)